Cannot open an interactive window in VS Code
I was messing with my settings, trying to get pytest working in VS Code and now I'm not able to open interactive windows at all. If I try to run code in an interactive window nothing happens (no error message anywhere I can see). I've been working in VS Code for years and never had any trouble with this. Python still works, as I can run my files non-interactively.
I wish I could provide more info about specific settings I changed, but one thing I know for sure is I deleted everything in the settings.json file
Here are some (potentially unrelated) symptoms I'm also noticing:

I'm getting a consistent notification that VS Code is 'Reactivating Terminals', but it never resolves
I can create a Jupyter notebook, but it never detects any kernels
The text editor does not recognize any of my imports (i.e, they are not being color coded as expected..these include things like os and sys that clearly have no typos)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code, Python, and the Python and Jupyter notebook extensions in VS Code.
I even restored my system back to a day prior, before I had made any of the changes, without success.
Any ideas or help at all would be greatly appreciated.

try to do clean uninstall, guide here

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? Maybe "how do I reset VSCode settings"? There are existing questions about that, like How do I factory reset Visual Studio Code. Or if you want to ask about troubleshooting the interactive window specifically, there are a bunch of things to check, like try manually running the command "Jupyter: Create Interactive Window" and see what happens. You can [edit] to clarify. For tips, check out [ask].

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post.
